# Improving copying bytes from an Image

Tags: python, image

I have the following minimal code that gets the bytes from an image:

```
import Image

im = Image.open("kitten.png")
im_data = [pix for pixdata in im.getdata() for pix in pixdata]
```

This is rather slow (I have gigabytes of images to process) so how could this be sped up? I'm also unfamiliar with what exactly that code is trying to do. All my data is 1280 x 960 x 8-bit RGB, so I can ignore corner cases, etc.

(FYI, the full code is [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11537/creating-a-bag-file-out-of-a-image-sequence/) - I've already replaced the `ImageFile` loop with the above `Image.open()`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
scipy.ndimage.imread()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean speeding up by algorythamically i can suggest you accessing file with multiple threads simultaneously (only if you don't have a connection between processing sequence)

divide file logically by few sections and access each part simultaneously with threads (you have to put your operation inside a function and call it with threads)

here is a link to tutorial about threading in python

[threding in python](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: No, I mean speeding up the single process.

Comment: so then i dont think you have much options here becoz o/s only gives you a sheared window and resources to run your process with others so it have a limit of reading and processing, that is the limit you see here  , you cant pass it and speed up your program.the only way is to by more slots and do simultaneous processing,

there is another thing that u can do if you like to access the picture by sequantly get big chunk of bytes and you can do the processes simultaneously for those bytes by dividing them into small pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I think:

```
>>> [pix for pixdata in im.getdata() for pix in pixdata] ==
           numpy.ndarray.tolist(numpy.ndarray.flatten(numpy.asarray(im)))
True
```

This cuts down the runtime by half, and with a bit of `bash` magic I can run the conversion on the 56 directories in parallel.